# Cannot inner join

Tags: mysql, join

I've been struggling with this for 2 days.
This is what I have so far

```
BEGIN
DECLARE s TEXT DEFAULT '';
select 
    u.*,
    h.*,
    last_hash(h.ref) as `last_one`
from users u
    join user_hash h
    on h.ref = u.id
    and h.hash = `last_one`
    ;
END
```

The function `last_one` returns the last hash in the table for the user trying to log in (meaning a user can change their passwords and a copy of the old hashes will be saved meaning they can't use the same password again for a set duration).
If I run this without the `and h.hash = last_one` I get the correct results, with the column `last_one` included in the result.
However, with the clause I get an error saying the column does not exist.

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'last_one' in 'on clause'
```

If I change the clause to a `where` clause after the join I get `unknown column in 'where clause'`.
It's worth mentioning that I already have a working version of this, but I would like to do it with one select and no variables, if possible.
Any reason the column wouldn't be recognised inside or outside of the join?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous topic title, I put that in while I wrote out the question, then forgot to elaborate. Apologies.

Comment: You cannot reference an alias from the SELECT in the FROM or WHERE; MySQL does allow referencing them in the `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `ORDER BY` clauses, but in other RDBMS those aliases cannot be used anywhere within the query. _Aliases in subqueries can be referenced in the queries wrapping them._

Comment: You cannot use an alias declared in select clause , as a regular column in other clauses such as join, where etc. Use the expression again where ever u need it.

Comment: Using the function directly in the clause (`having` produces no rows, this is what I did first and is what prompted me to try adding it as a virtual row. Does `having` need to reference a native function? I have also tried `having` using the `MAX(h.created)`, as this may produce the same result, I still get an empty row. Maybe my understanding of the having clause is below par.

Comment: If you tried HAVING, were you also using GROUP BY? Without any actual aggregation, a GROUP BY could have messed with the results before reaching HAVING _(some RDBMS do not allow using HAVING without GROUP BY, but MySQL does)_. ....unless the real expression is much longer, what is so hard about just having `h.hash = last_hash(h.ref)` in the WHERE/join condition?

Answer (score 0):

may be it works with:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE s TEXT DEFAULT '';
select 
    u.*,
    h.*,
    last_hash(h.ref) as `last_one`
from users u
    join user_hash h
    on h.ref = u.id
    and h.hash = last_hash(h.ref)
    ;
END
```

Comment: That returns without error, however no rows are returned. I have confirmed that `last_hash` does actually return the last hash for the selected reference. I think this prompted me to create the 'virtual column' in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a column alias (`last_one`) in the ON clause. You need to either repeat the function call in the ON clause:

```
select 
    u.*,
    h.*,
    last_hash(h.ref) as `last_one`
from users u
    join user_hash h
    on h.ref = u.id
    and h.hash = last_hash(h.ref)
```

or use it the HAVING clause or use a subquery.

However - In this case, since `h.hash = last_hash(h.ref)` and it is an INNER JOIN, you can replace the function call in the SELECT clause with `h.hash`:

```
select 
    u.*,
    h.*,
    h.hash as `last_one`
from users u
    join user_hash h
    on h.ref = u.id
    and h.hash = last_hash(h.ref)
```

And since `h.ref = u.id` you can replace `last_hash(h.ref)` with `last_hash(u.id)`, which should result in a better performance.

Comment: That returns without error, however no rows are returned. I have confirmed that `last_hash` does actually return the last hash for the selected reference. I think this prompted me to create the 'virtual column' in the first place.

Comment: @Mike consider to create and post sample data, which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: users table contains `ID`, `created`, `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`
user_hash contains `ID`, `created`, `ref`, `hash`, `salt`

Answer (score 0):

Many apologies, seems that I made a critical error in the `last_hash(int)` function. Posting this function may have saved us all some time. Live and learn.

I had it set to return a `VARCHAR(50)` when the hashes are `VARCHAR(128)`. Correcting this fixed the problem.

I didn't catch it because, as stated originally, when adding the `last_hash(int)` function as a column I got all 128 characters in the results, had I only got 50 I would of noticed right away. This lead me to think the query was the problem.

Thanks once again for your time.

Comment: When you were creating your question post, weren't you automatically told that with problem code you should give a [mre]? See also [ask] & [help].

Comment: Are you suggesting I post my tables, functions and data? I have apologised and I accept it was my error, which I did not have to do, I could of just ignored this thread from on. I assumed the query was the problem, which I did indeed post, as well as background information. I am sorry my question and it's content did not meet with your approval.

Comment: Hi. The link & I are not just suggesting but telling you to post those in your question & the link says it clearly so I don't know why you ask. Code questions without a [mre] should be downvoted & closed. I asked whether you were prompted for a MRE because if you were then it's not a matter of "live & learn" but of please do as asked & what did you expect. To avoid future downvotes, you can edit your question to have a MRE. Or delete it while there are no upvotes or accepted answers. But please don't delete a post with helpful answers. But answers here preceded a MRE & are not very helpful.